# Rename dataframe columns by mapping with a dictionary but keeping original if no match

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

Say I have the following data:

```
dfData = pd.DataFrame({
    'A1':['1','2'],
    'B1':['1','2'],
    'C1':['1','2'],
    'D1':['1','2']
    })
print(dfData)
```

| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

And I set the following map:

```
dfMap = pd.DataFrame({
    'dfDataCol':['A1','B1','C1',''],
    'NewCol'   :['A2','B2','C2','D2']
    })
print(dfMap)
```

| dfDataCol | NewCol |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 |
| B1 | B2 |
| C1 | C2 |

I convert to a dictionary and map the names:

```
dict1 = dfMap.set_index('dfDataCol').to_dict()['NewCol']
dfData.columns = dfData.columns.map(dict1)
```

I get:

| A2 | B2 | C2 | NaN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

How do I keep the original heading if there is no dictionary entry:

| A2 | B2 | C2 | D1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
dfData = dfData.rename(columns=dict1)

print(dfData)
```

Prints:

```
  A2 B2 C2 D1
0  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2
```